# Postgres: how can a "select count(*)" cause dirty blocks?

Tags: sql, postgresql, caching

While trying to optimize some queries in Postgres 11, I stumbled upon this behavior I can't understand.

```
> explain (analyze, buffers) select count(*) from events;
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2533599.69..2533599.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=113869.828..113869.828 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=204077 read=2205033 dirtied=16112
   I/O Timings: read=319766.985
   ->  Gather  (cost=2533599.48..2533599.69 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=113869.814..113871.340 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=204077 read=2205033 dirtied=16112
         I/O Timings: read=319766.985
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2532599.48..2532599.49 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=113866.031..113866.032 rows=1 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=204077 read=2205033 dirtied=16112
               I/O Timings: read=319766.985
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..2507901.58 rows=9879158 width=0) (actual time=0.048..111664.011 rows=8055167 loops=3)
                     Buffers: shared hit=204077 read=2205033 dirtied=16112
                     I/O Timings: read=319766.985
 Planning Time: 0.142 ms
 Execution Time: 113871.415 ms
```

My understanding here is that my `select count(*)` dirtied 16112 blocks.

Two questions:

- Am I understanding this right?
- How can a read-only operation make blocks dirty?

Comment: This was answered over at [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81184)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer that, I have to explain something about PostgreSQL internals.

In PostgreSQL, rows are never updated in place. Rather, each `UPDATE` creates a new version of the row. Similarly, a `DELETE` does not remove the row, but marks it as invalid.

Each row version carries the ID of the transaction that created it and of the transaction that marked it as invalid. Together, these transaction IDs determine the *visibility* of a row version.

`COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` do not touch the table at all, they only mark the transaction committed or aborted in the *commit log*.

Now a query that reads a row version has to consult that commit log to determine if it can see a row version or not. For example, if the transaction that created a row version is rolled back, the row version is invisible.

You can imagine that this would create a lot of traffic on the commit log, which would hurt performance, if there were no optimization in place: If a statement accessing a row finds that the creating or deleting transaction is ended, it will set a so-called *hint bit* on the row version. Subsequent readers now don't have to consult the commit log any more.

Your query was the first to read some of the rows in the table, so it set those hint bits. This modification makes the block containing the row version "dirty", that is, it has to be written to storage.

This explains how reading queries can end up writing data in PostgreSQL. For that reason, it is often a good idea to `VACUUM` a table after a bulk data modification: it will take the onus of setting hint bits from the first reader.